# Connecting USB connectors

Tags: usb

I am building something where I have a USB type B connector routed to a type A connector. Do I have to swap the D- and D+ lines or are they connected D- to D- and D+ to D+? In the attached picture, pin 3 of K1 is D+ and pin 2 is D-. Is this schematic correct for connecting Type B to Type A?

[image: USB Connectors Schematic]

Comment: As far as I know there's no reason to swap them. So yes, your schematic is correct.

Comment: Yes, the connections are all right.

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic is correct - D+ and D- are bidirectional differential signals, hence there is no need to swap. In fact, if you do, your device will not work.